# How to add free space to C: drive?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive

This question is about how can I add `free space` of my hard disk to `C:` drive?
Below is image taken from
`computer>properties>manage>Disk Mangement`

As I have `212.59 GB` free space(shown in red box) ,how can I add it to `C: drive`(shown in circle)
[image]

Comment: Can you upload a larger screenshot?  It looks like your OS is using that partition for something, but the graphic you posted doesn't have enough fine detail.

Comment: Doesn't Right-clicking the C: partition and hitting "Extend volume" work as expected?

Comment: @Colyn1337 The screen shot is sized by the site, if you want to see a larger version of it, try dragging it to the title bar or a new tab in your browser.

Comment: No it does not,only shrink is available.

Comment: do you need to run the disk man elevated? or possibly change the `free space` to `unallocated`...then right click the c: partition and expand?

Comment: You should just be able to extend the partition. Are you unable to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the picture a little harder, the green outline gave it away to me.

Your "free space" is inside an Extended partition (vs. a Primary).  You need to delete that extended partition so that the area is unassigned, and then you should be able to right-click the C: volume and hit "Extend volume".